# PHP: json_encode - Using foreach() and encoding html elements for json

Tags: php, api, json

I am trying to parse articles from mysql and encode the data in json with php.

Currently publishing articles I use:

```
<?php if ($success): ?>
    <?php foreach($article->get_items() as $item): ?>

    <?php echo $item->get_content(); ?>


    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and I am trying to **encode this into json**.

I have tried this:

```
<?php if ($success): ?>
    <?php foreach($feed->get_items() as $item): ?>

    <?php
    $data = array(
        'id'    =>    "1",
        'result'       =>    array(
                            'title'    =>   'This is the title',
                            'publish'   =>  'John Doe',
                            'content'    =>  $item->get_content()
                     )
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, **I'm not sure how I would use foreach()** so that I could parse and encode all the content.

UPDATE:

The content parsed from **$item->get_content()** has HTML elements such as ,  etc. so they should be encoded into json or strings ?

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem is that currently I end up with this:

```
[
{"id":"1","result":{"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"}},
{"id":"1","result":{"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"}},
{"id":"1","result":{"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"}},
{"id":"1","result":{"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"}},
{"id":"1","result":{"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"}}
]
```

because **I am not using foreach() properly** and I want to end up with this:

```
[
{"id":"1","result": {"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"},
            {"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"},
            {"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"},
            {"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"},
            {"title":"This is the title","publish":"John Doe","content":"content 1"}
]
```

and also the **content sometimes it contains html elements** which destroys the json encoding so I would imagine I have to encode it into json or string?

Comment: Take out the `echo` in `content`'s value and you should be fine.

Comment: Don't break out of `<?php` unless you have to. Here, you definitely do not want to.

Comment: @Interrobang Sorry it was just a wrong paste. Updated.

Comment: @Eric Sorry it was just a wrong paste. Updated.

Comment: "parse articles" -- What?

Comment: What's actually wrong with your code? I don't understand your problem. Do you want just one JSON encoded string containing all feed items?

Comment: @MichaelRushton Please see update 2.

Comment: Re. the HTML problem: when outputting use something like `echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data));` (although don't use this when you want to decode the string again).

Comment: @MichaelRushton when wouldn't you want to decode it again? I'm pretty sure this will rather be a response handled by JavaScript than by a human eye. On the other hand... if "html elements destroy the encoding" this might indeed be the case. The vocabulary in this question is confusing.

Comment: I meant that he shouldn't use the `htmlspecialchars` on the variable he'll be decoding/passing to `JavaScript`. It should only be used when *outputting* the string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an array that holds all the data and then encode it to `json`

```
if ($success){
    $result = array();
    foreach($feed->get_items() as $item){
        $data = array(
             'id'    =>    "1",
             'result'       =>    array(
                   'title'    =>   'This is the title',
                   'publish'  =>  'John Doe',
                   'content'  =>  $item->get_content()
             )
         );
         array_push($result,$data);
    }                
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Don't wrap every line in a `<?php ... ?>`!

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
foreach($article->get_items() as $item){
    $result[] = array(
            'title'   => 'This is the title',
            'publish' => 'John Doe',
            'content' => $item->get_content()
        );
    );
}

echo json_encode(array('id'=>'1', 'result'=>$result));
?>
```

Actually I'm not sure I understand what you need so maybe it wouldn't help.

Comment: @eric I want to have only I result array and within that the 'foreach()' statement. Im just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Just change the last line to `echo json_encode($data);` You have to encode the final array once, it can't be done within the foreach loop.

Comment: @JohnyBryne is there anything wrong with this code except your worrying for HTML in JSON? It will work fine with string array field containing HTML tags

Comment: `echo $item->get_content()` should be `$item->get_content()` here

Comment: @yefrem Plesae do check update 2 which I think it explains better what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @JohnyBryne check updated answer. Also I never had a problem with HTML in json_encode

Comment: @yefrem Unexpected ');' on line 8.

Comment: @JohnyBryne added missing ";" but you better check small things like that yourself

Answer (score 2):

When outputting a string that contains `HTML` code, you'll want to use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data));
```

For example:

```
$data = array('id' => '<hello>');

echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data));

// Outputs: {"id":"<hello>"}
```

Comment: Great! That gets the job done. Do you also know the solution for the foreach() after result array has been created?